# Unable to view VBA code on VPC

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vpc, vba

I have VPC running on my machine. Both main machine and VPC has same office versions [office 2007]. When I open an excel on main machine then I can navigate to VBA code window by clicking on 'Visual Basic' ribbon button available under Developer tab but same button is disabled on my VPC. Due to which I am unable to view code/add my customized add-in in excel available on my VPC.
Does any one has any idea about what could be an issue.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just FYI... The macros are already enbaled with the Trust Center settings.

Comment: Try to edit a macro, it will enter the VBE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First be sure the developer Tab is enabled correctly

> 1. Click the Microsoft Office ButtonButton image, and then click Excel Options, PowerPoint Options, or Word Options.
> 2. Click Popular, and then select the Show Developer tab in the Ribbon check box.

Then enable all the reasonable Trust options in the "Trust Center"

If it is still greyed out, the most probable reason is that VBA was not installed with Excel. Pick your *original* Office CD and reinstall VBA.

HTH!